# StreamPlot in a system x´ = f[x] + g[t]

Tags: differential-equations

`StreamPlot` can be used in the O.D.E system:

x' = 2 x - 3 y + 3 t

y' = 5 x +  y - t

How?

```
StreamPlot[{2 x - 3 y, 5 x + y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Not include "t"

Comment: Maybe this is the sort of thing you want: `Manipulate[StreamPlot[{2 x - 3 y + 3 t, 5 x + y - t}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], {{t, 0, "t"}, -5, 5}]`,

Comment: Welcome! Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this system of DEs is not autonomous. A slope field / stream plot / phase plane is not possible here, at least, not without a very clever trick (see Wolfgang's answer). But an x vs y stream plot is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Stephen Luttrell's proposal your example can be treated as follows.
Letting z = y-t the system becomes

x' = 2 x - 3 z
z' = 5x + z + 1

which is independent of t, and we can do the StreamPlot

```
StreamPlot[{2 x - 3 z, 5 x + z + 1}, {x, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
(* 141102_streamplot.jpg *)
```

[image]

Regards,
Wolfgang